# how to use custom font as Genericons

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I want to use custom Genericons please guide me the way I should do this.I have done a quick searching but didn't found any good example it would be great if any one can share any link related to this.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/making-use-of-the-genericons-font-in-your-website--wp-34298

Answer (score 1):

Flaticon offers icon fonts for web usage. See if this helps you...

http://www.flaticon.com/